# Parsing Bash Command Output

Tags: bash

Suppose I use

`find` (some stuff) `| wc -l`

Then I have output like

```
14 file1.txt
29 file2.txt
32 file3.txt
1  tile4.txt
```

I'm completely new to Bash scripts but what I want to happen is that I can use this output right away after the command to write to another file. For example, if the count is greater than 10, I want to write `"ALERT! Count for file#.txt is greater than 10!"` in `myotherfile.txt`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

```
find ... -exec wc -l {} + |
while read count file
do
    if [ $count -gt 10 ]
    then echo "ALERT! Count for $file is $count" >>myotherfile.txt
    fi
done
```

The residual problem is buffering in the pipeline; there isn't an easy way to stop that.  The use of `>> myotherfile.txt` is partially to address that.  It would be simpler in some respects to use redirection on the loop as a whole (`done > myotherfile.txt`, with no `>>` redirection), but there would be more buffering like that.

Note that your proposed pipeline:

```
find ... | wc -l
```

will not count the lines in each file; it will only count the number of lines generated by the `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do the trick.

```
find [some stuff] | wc -l | awk '$1 > 10 {print "ALERT! Count for " $2 " is greater than 10!"}' > myotherfile.txt
```

Note that this will overwrite `myotherfile.txt` everytime you run the command.  If you want the lines to be added to the end of the file instead every time you run it, use `>>` instead of `>`.